# Is error handling for asynchronous lambda invocations using a queue is a good way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, queue

I have a Lambda function which handles a critical function which runs against our database. I need to make sure that this runs at least once and if it fails after three times send an Email. Currently, I am using a queue to trigger lambda and if lambda fails for three times message will be sent to a dead letter queue which will handle sending emails.

But as I read the AWS Doc for Lambda, it says Lambda already retry for three times. If so without using a queue I can just send the email from the same Lambda function without using queues. Is this a 100% failsafe way to handle errors in a Lambda function? If not is using the queues is the right way?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a 100% failsafe way to handle errors in a Lambda function?

No.

> If not is using the queues is the right way?

Yes, if configured properly.

The [Lambda Retry Behaviour](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html) says it retries two more times if the invocation is ***asynchronous***. SQS is a poll-based system. Lambda will poll the Queue and all of its invocations will be ***synchronous***.

> For poll-based AWS services (Amazon Kinesis, Amazon DynamoDB, Amazon
>   Simple Queue Service), AWS Lambda polls the stream or message queue
>   and invokes your Lambda function synchronously.

If you want to wait until your messages fail three times, set the `maxReceiveCount` attribute to 3 on your source SQS queue. Although the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-eventsource) doesn't explicitly mention the `maxReceiveCount` for SQS queues configured as an event source, it also applies. Once the threshold under `maxReceiveCount` is reached, the message will then be redirected to the configured DLQ. Keep in mind that you need to configure a DLQ on your Source SQS queue and not on the Lambda function itself.

Comment: What if invocation is done as asynchronous? If so is there a need of using queues to be 100% failsafe?

Comment: Then the retry behavior is different. I suggest you take a look into the links I shared so you can decide what’s better for your use case